# How to implement 3D Touch preview action with left or right swipe?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, 3dtouch

I know how to add `UIPreviewActionItem` when swipe from the bottom. There is a method `previewActionItems()`. But how to do the following thing:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Left and right swipe is a custom implementation by Apple engineers. Broke my heart when I found that out as well.

Answer (score 0):

As Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/3DTouch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH71) says:

> Provide peek quick actions, if appropriate. Within a peek, users can **swipe up** to reveal actions that are related to the item.

There is nothing about left/right swipe.